# fgets() & execvp() segfault

Tags: c, fgets

I'm sorry I couldn't be more descriptive with the title, but I don't know any other way to explain it.

Anyways, I'm writing this shell like thing as a hobby and I'm having trouble regarding `fgets()` and `execvp()` where the code compiles successfully but on runtime no matter what you type it crashes.

Here is the code in question:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
 
char *CASH_ARGS[1024]; // arguments
char CASH_EXEC[128]; // file shell will be executing
 
void CASH_CMD() // command handling
{
 // get executable and arguments
 scanf("%s",CASH_EXEC);
 fgets(*CASH_ARGS,sizeof(CASH_ARGS),stdin);
  
 // pipe to execvp()
 execvp(CASH_EXEC,CASH_ARGS);
}
```

Yes, I know its a function and i have it like this since the function itself is ran in a separate file for other reasons.

Thank you in advance, have a nice day.

Comment: no why? it warned about it before i added that * in front of CASH_ARGS

Comment: `*CASH_ARGS` is `NULL`. Try removing both stars. `fgets` inputs *one string*.

Comment: You never initialized any of the pointers in the `CASH_ARGS` array.

Comment: You need to read the user input into a string. Then you can use `strtok()` to split that string into tokens, and set the elements of `CASH_ARGS` to point to these tokens. You also need a `NULL` sentinel at the end.

Comment: `sizeof(CASH_ARGS)` this is the size of `1024` pointers. Probably not what you want. Also `fgets` reads one line into a string. Not multiple strings.

Answer (score 0):

1. You're passing an uninitialized pointer to `fgets()`.
2. `fgets()` reads a single string, it doesn't split it into an array of strings. You can use `strtok()` to do this.
3. `CASH_ARGS[0]` should be the name of the program being executed. The arguments start at `CASH_ARGS[1]`.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
 
char *CASH_ARGS[1024]; // arguments
char CASH_EXEC[128]; // file shell will be executing
char cash_input[1000]; // arguments as a string
 
void CASH_CMD() // command handling
{
    // get executable and arguments
    scanf("%s",CASH_EXEC);
    CASH_ARGS[0] = CASH_EXEC;

    fgets(cash_input,sizeof(cash_input),stdin);
    int i = 1;
    while (1) {
        char *token = strtok(cash_input, " \n");
        CASH_ARGS[i] = token;
        if (!token) {
            break;
        }
    }

    // pipe to execvp()
    execvp(CASH_EXEC,CASH_ARGS);
}
```

Comment: i never wanted to split it into an array of strings, I had it like that so that way i can have all arguments in one string then pass it to execvp

Comment: `execvp` doesn't want one string, it requires an array of strings.

Comment: Do you want the input to be just one argument to the command? Then use `execlp` instead of `execvp`